# localStorage not being persisted in hybrid app in Android M42

Tags: android, cordova

In the latest release of ·Android System WebView (M42 42.0.2311.129)· there seems to be issues with localStorage in hybrid apps.

I've submitted a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481380) but I am trying to find a workaround for objects not being persisted in localStorage.

This is taken from the bug report：

```
Steps to reproduce the problem:
1. Start hybrid app built with phonegap
2. In app, call javascript localStorage.setItem("m42bug","test for localstorage")
3. Through developer tools debugging confirm object has been stored: localStorage.getItem("m42bug")
4. Close app 
(swipe it away, force close it or restarting the device all cause the same)
5. Start app
6. In app, call javascript localStorage.getItem("m42bug")
```

What is the expected behavior?

`localStorage.getItem("m42bug")` should return the value "test for localstorage"

What went wrong?

`localStorage.getItem("m42bug")` returns null.

`Object.keys(localStorage)` indicate there is no key for `m42bug`

Comment: Is there any alternatives to store persistent datas.
Removing localStorage is intended or it is a bug ?

Comment: definitively a bug which is prioritized by Google. Looks like they want to patch M42, but the fix is still not prioritized. You can follow up the status here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479767 . Only workaround now is to use IndexedDB

Answer (score 1):

Faced the exact same problem. For a workaround we store the localstorage data on the phone on exit from the app and restore it from there on app start. Works fine :) Hope it helps :)

Comment: could you add a bit more details on how you are storing the localStorage data on exit from the app and how you restore it?

Comment: are you using the org.apache.cordova.file plugin ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html

Answer (score 1):

Is a bug, I reported [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479767) and it affects not just WebView but webapps (Chrome) too.

In my case, I moved from `localStorage` to `IndexedDB`, that seems to work ok. In fact, I'm rewriting all the data management of my app to `ForerunnerDB`and it works great.